# Rails 3.2.8 - routing and link_to_paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to refactor my 3.0 app to another server running 3.2.8, and it appears routing syntax may have changed a bit?

Given this routes.rb:

```
root :to => 'user_sessions#new'
match 'login' => 'user_sessions#new'
match 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy'
match 'usermenu' => 'users#menu'
match 'adminmenu' => 'users#adminmenu'
```

And this view:

```
<% if current_user %>  
  <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>  |  
  <%= link_to "Main Menu", usermenu_path %>  |  
  <%= link_to_if (current_user.admin == true, "Admin Menu", adminmenu_path) %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (/home/-/layouts/application.html.erb:19: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...if (current_user.admin == true, "Admin Menu", adminmenu_path...

/home/-/layouts/application.html.erb:19: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...er.admin == true, "Admin Menu", adminmenu_path) );@output_bu...
                          ^):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a space between link_to_if and the opening parenthesis

```
link_to_if (current_user.admin == true, "Admin Menu", adminmenu_path)
```

should be

```
link_to_if(current_user.admin == true, "Admin Menu", adminmenu_path)
```

Routes haven't changed.